# Cannot access cookies after redirect in django

Tags: python, django, ajax, cookies

Here is situation I've dealt with. I will try to explain as much as easier to understand.

I want user to click on a button in the website (let's name this site A) which fires an ajax post request to django view. Within this view I have `response.set_cookie` to set cookie with data that is passed along with ajax post request.

After success response, then I quickly redirect page to different website (let say this site is B). When page loads, I want to access cookies what I've set from site A but cannot access.

Below is my code.

**index.html (in site A, where the ajax post request is made)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick=setCookies()>Create Invoice</button>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    const setCookies = () => {

        ...some codes...

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

        const data = {
            'HTTP_LOGIN_TYPE': 'admin',
        }

        $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                url: url, // hits endpoint where sets cookies.
                crossDomain: true,
                data: data,
                success: () => {
                    window.location.href = to site B
                },
                error: xhr => {
                    console.log(xhr.responseText)
                }
            }
        )
    }
</script>

</html>
```

**views.py (in site B, where sets the cookies)**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class AuthenticateUser(APIView):

    def post(self, request):

        data = request.POST
        login_type = data['HTTP_LOGIN_TYPE']

        if login_type == 'admin':
            response = HttpResponse(
                'Setting login_type to %s' % login_type)
            response.set_cookie(
                'login_type', login_type, max_age=604800, domain=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN)

            return response
```

**views.py (in site B, redirected from ajax call in index.html, where I want to access cookies)**

```
import re
from django.db import DatabaseError
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.renderers import TemplateHTMLRenderer
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class GetInvoice(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'student/base.html'

    def get(self, request, student_id):

        login_type = 'hello'

        if 'login_type' in request.COOKIES:
            login_type = request.COOKIES['login_type'] # Can't access cookies

       ... more code ...
```

FYI, `url` in `index.html` and site B's domain are same, though site A and B's domains are different.

I am not sure what am I missing. I've been searching articles, posts, etc for last couple days and tried based on them but no luck.

Correct me if I missed anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the [Same-origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), you cannot access the cookies for a different domain.

> Access to data stored in the browser such as localStorage and
>   IndexedDB are separated by origin. Each origin gets its own separate
>   storage, and JavaScript in one origin cannot read from or write to the
>   storage belonging to another origin.

However, if domain B is a subdomain of A, it will automatically have visibility into the cookies for domain A. If you cannot change the domains, you should redirect to site B with the cookies in the request headers/body.